# Search by multiple datetime units

Tags: java, date, search

In a form, I have 4 fields where the user can select the date in a list to search for an event that happened on that date:

- year
- month
- day
- hour

So far it works only when none of the fields is selected (so the result is all the events that ever happened), or only when all fields are selected (so the result is all events that happened in that hour of that day of that month of that year).

My problem is that I don't know how to search if only a month or a year and an hour is selected (all 4^4 combinations possible). How can I achieve this?

Comment: I would take a step back and wonder: which user would ever want to find all the events in 2016 starting at 2 o'clock? Will any user ever be interested in doing such a query? I think not. But other than that, the problem is pretty simple: is the user enters the year, then add a criterion on the year. If he enters a month, add a criterion on the month. same for the two others. Then search for events satisfying all the criteria.

Comment: Thank you, I will try your way

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is vague as it does not address your goal. I will assume you are gathering input for some kind of query against a date range.

So I suppose it makes sense to have a year alone, or a year+month, or a year+month+dayOfMonth, or a year+month+dayOfMonth+Hour but no other combinations.

## Date-time values

Use the java.time classes to determine dates or date-times for searching.

For year only, use [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Year.html) class.

```
if( yearOnly ) {
    Year year = Year.of( Integer.intValue( yearFieldValue ) );
    LocalDate yearStartDate = year.atDay( 1 );
    LocalDate yearStopDate = year.atDay( year.length() ); // Year is normally 365 or 366 days long ([Leap Year][2]).
}
```

Or if you are wisely using the Half-Open approach to defining a span of time, where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive* that would mean a year starts on the first of the year and runs up to, but does *not* include, the first of the following year.

```
if( yearOnly ) {
    Year year = Year.of( Integer.intValue( yearFieldValue ) );
    LocalDate targetYearStartDate = year.atDay( 1 );
    LocalDate followingYearStartDate = targetYearStartDate.plusYears( 1 );
}
```

If you need exact moments, get the first moment of each day. Specify a time zone as when the date starts varies around the globe by zone. Apply a `ZoneId` to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdtStart = targetYearStartDate.atStartOfDay( z );
ZonedDateTime zdtStop = followingYearStartDate.atStartOfDay( z );
```

If they provide year and month but no date and no hour, use [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html).

```
YearMonth ymStart = YearMonth.of( Integer.intValue( yearFieldValue ) , Integer.intValue( monthFieldValue ) );
LocalDate ldStart = ymStart.atDay( 1 );
LocalDate ldStop = ym.plusMonths( 1 ).atDay( 1 );
```

If you get year and month and day-of-month, do straight to a `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of(
    Integer.intValue( yearFieldValue ) , 
    Integer.intValue( monthFieldValue ) , 
    Integer.intValue( dayOfMonthFieldValue )
)
```

If you also get an hour, then construct a [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html). Combine with `LocalDate` and `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( Integer.intValue( hourFieldValue ) , 0 );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z );
```

## User Interface

In terms of user interface, you could enable only the year field at first. Once a valid value is entered, enable the next field, and so on.

If you cannot do that, then one approach is to not address bad entries. If they enter year and dayOfMonth but no month, just go with searching for the entire year, for example.

If you want to address bad data entry, then you need to do the checking with your code, looking for each good and bad combination.